# Can't place connect 4 chips in lowest available spot

Tags: java, processing

This code is all based in the Java programming language, specifically processing. The website I'm using is OpenProcessing for school.

In my Connect 4 code I'm trying to place the chips at the lowest possible available spot. I have a checkSpace integer which is supposed to recognize if that space if available by getting the color value of the x and y value where the piece is supposed to go. If the x and y value is colored white, then the piece is placed. If it isn't, then the y value moves up and checks that value. Here is the code for reference:

```
int checkSpace(int x) {
        for(int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(get(x, 150 + (i*100)) == color(255))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
}
```

The next segment of code places the chip itself, which is where it isn't working. Well, it might not be working because of the code shown above, so please let me know if that is the problem.
Anyways, the next segment of code starts with a void mouseReleased, so that when the user clicks their mouse they can place their chip. It continues with an if statement which identifies which player's turn it is. It then goes on with x value identifications using if statements, checking which part of the grid the mouse is in. Here is the whole code, it's long but please bear with it:

```
void mouseReleased() {
    if(player1Turn) {
        if(mouseX <= 100) {
            if(checkSpace(50) != -1) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse((checkSpace(50)), 50, 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 100 && mouseX <= 200){
            if(checkSpace(150) != -1) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse(150, (checkSpace(150)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        
        }
        if(mouseX > 200 && mouseX <= 300) {
            if(checkSpace(250) != -1) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse(250, (checkSpace(250)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        
        }
        if(mouseX > 300 && mouseX <= 400) {
            if(checkSpace(350) != -1) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse(3500, (checkSpace(350)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 400 && mouseX <= 500) {
            if(checkSpace(450) != -1) {
                fill(255,0,0);
                ellipse(450, (checkSpace(450)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 500 && mouseX <= 600) {
            if(checkSpace(550) != -1) {
                fill(255,0,0);
                ellipse(550, (checkSpace(550)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if (mouseX > 600 && mouseX <= 700) {
            if(checkSpace(650) != -1) {
                fill(255,0,0);
                ellipse(550, (checkSpace(550)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
                }
        }
        
    }
    else {
        if(mouseX <= 100) {
            if(checkSpace(50) != -1) {
                fill(255, 255, 0);
                ellipse(50, (checkSpace(50)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 100 && mouseX <= 200){
            if(checkSpace(150) != -1) {
                fill(255, 255, 0);
                ellipse(150, (checkSpace(150)), 50, 50);
            
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        
        }
        if(mouseX > 200 && mouseX <= 300) {
            if(checkSpace(250) != -1) {
                fill(255, 255, 0);
                ellipse(250, (checkSpace(250)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        
        }
        if(mouseX >300 && mouseX <= 400) {
            if(checkSpace(350) != -1) {
                fill(255, 255, 0);
                ellipse(350, (checkSpace(350)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 400 && mouseX <= 500) {
            if(checkSpace(450) != -1) {
                fill(255,255,0);
                ellipse(450, (checkSpace(450)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 500 && mouseX <= 600) {
            if(checkSpace(550) != -1) {
                fill(255,255,0);
                ellipse(550, (checkSpace(550)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if (mouseX > 600 && mouseX <= 700) {
            if(checkSpace(650) != -1) {
                fill(255,255,0);
                ellipse(650, (checkSpace(650)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
                }
        }
            
    
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I'm really stuck, and I have no idea how to continue. Thanks for any help you can give me. I'll paste the whole code down here for those who want a more in depth look if the problem isn't in any of the code above. I haven't created a win-identification part of the code yet, so as of now the only purpose for the code is to place a chip at the lowest available spot. Here is the code:

```
int red = color(255,0,0);
int yellow = color(255,255,0);
boolean player1Turn = true;
int x = 7, y = 6;
int turn = 0;
int player = 0;
int grid[y][x] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9},
    {9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}
};

void setup(){
    size(700, 600);
    background(255);
}
void draw(){
    for (int y = 0; y < grid.length-1; y++) {
       for (int x = 0; x < grid[y].length-1; x++) {
                 fill(255);
                 rect(x * 100, y * 100, 99, 99);
             }
    }
    playGame();
}
void playGame() {
    if(player1Turn){
        player1();
    }
    else {
        player2();
    }
}

void player1(){
    fill(255,0,0,100);
    if(mouseX <= 100) {
        ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 100 && mouseX <= 200){
        ellipse(150, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 200 && mouseX <= 300){
        ellipse(250, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    else if(mouseX >300 && mouseX <= 400){
        ellipse(350,50,50,50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 400 && mouseX <= 500){
        ellipse(450,50,50,50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 500 && mouseX <= 600){
        ellipse(550,50,50,50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 600 && mouseX <= 700){
        ellipse(650,50,50,50);
    }
}

void player2() {
    fill(255, 255, 0, 100);
    if (mouseX > -1 && mouseX <= 100){
        ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 100 && mouseX <= 200){
        ellipse(150, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 200 && mouseX <= 300){
        ellipse(250, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 300 && mouseX <= 400){
        ellipse(350,50,50,50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 400 && mouseX <= 500){
        ellipse(450,50,50,50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 500 && mouseX <= 600){
        ellipse(550,50,50,50);
    }
    else if(mouseX > 600 && mouseX <= 700){
        ellipse(650,50,50,50);
    }
}

int checkSpace(int x) {
        for(int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(get(x, 150 + (i*100)) == color(255))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
}

void mouseReleased() {
    if(player1Turn) {
        if(mouseX <= 100) {
            if(checkSpace(50) != -1) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse((checkSpace(50)), 50, 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 100 && mouseX <= 200){
            if(checkSpace(150) != -1) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse(150, (checkSpace(150)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        
        }
        if(mouseX > 200 && mouseX <= 300) {
            if(checkSpace(250) != -1) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse(250, (checkSpace(250)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        
        }
        if(mouseX > 300 && mouseX <= 400) {
            if(checkSpace(350) != -1) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse(3500, (checkSpace(350)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 400 && mouseX <= 500) {
            if(checkSpace(450) != -1) {
                fill(255,0,0);
                ellipse(450, (checkSpace(450)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 500 && mouseX <= 600) {
            if(checkSpace(550) != -1) {
                fill(255,0,0);
                ellipse(550, (checkSpace(550)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if (mouseX > 600 && mouseX <= 700) {
            if(checkSpace(650) != -1) {
                fill(255,0,0);
                ellipse(550, (checkSpace(550)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
                }
        }
        
    }
    else {
        if(mouseX <= 100) {
            if(checkSpace(50) != -1) {
                fill(255, 255, 0);
                ellipse(50, (checkSpace(50)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 100 && mouseX <= 200){
            if(checkSpace(150) != -1) {
                fill(255, 255, 0);
                ellipse(150, (checkSpace(150)), 50, 50);
            
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        
        }
        if(mouseX > 200 && mouseX <= 300) {
            if(checkSpace(250) != -1) {
                fill(255, 255, 0);
                ellipse(250, (checkSpace(250)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        
        }
        if(mouseX >300 && mouseX <= 400) {
            if(checkSpace(350) != -1) {
                fill(255, 255, 0);
                ellipse(350, (checkSpace(350)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 400 && mouseX <= 500) {
            if(checkSpace(450) != -1) {
                fill(255,255,0);
                ellipse(450, (checkSpace(450)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if(mouseX > 500 && mouseX <= 600) {
            if(checkSpace(550) != -1) {
                fill(255,255,0);
                ellipse(550, (checkSpace(550)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
            }
        }
        if (mouseX > 600 && mouseX <= 700) {
            if(checkSpace(650) != -1) {
                fill(255,255,0);
                ellipse(650, (checkSpace(650)), 50, 50);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
                turn++;
                }
        }
            
    
    }
}
```

Again, thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3):

I just looked at the processing library.
https://processing.org/reference/

Draw is a continuously called function and it seems your draw function redraws the entire board continuously.  It is basically an infinite loop that is run, and then once done...runs again and so on.  So you want to initialize everything in setup which is run once at the start.

```
void setup(){
    size(700, 600);
    background(230);
    for (int y = 0; y < grid.length-1; y++) {
       for (int x = 0; x < grid[y].length-1; x++) {
             fill(245);
             rect(x * 100, y * 100, 99, 99);
       }
    }

}
```

So youre going to want to move this into setup to avoid rewriting the canvas and not seeing any updates.

Next, you notice that if you just leave playGame in draw like this:

```
void draw(){
    playGame();     
}
```

Then the ellipses will not be removed...that's because your player1() and player2() functions only place ellipses and since draw was continuously redrawing the entire canvas you got away with it.
One solution that I think would be good is if you create an extra bar so now there is a height of 6 and just have the ellipses spawn there and then have the draw function just overwrite that top bar.

Next, your checkSpace function is always returning -1.  For determining if a location is empty you should be maintaining a 2d array/matrix to store these details...which will also help you once you are checking to see if somebody has won.  Picture attached below.

[image: How the Matrix Should work]

[I mocked up a quick sketch on how I think the matrix should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr7AY.png)

Also since you are learning...this is completely valid

```
    if(mouseX <= 100) {
        if(checkSpace(50) != -1) {
            fill(255, 0, 0);   
            ellipse((checkSpace(50)), 50, 50, 50);
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
            turn++;
        }
    }
    else if(mouseX <= 200){
        if(checkSpace(150) != -1) {
            fill(255, 0, 0);
            ellipse(150, (checkSpace(150)), 50, 50);
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
            turn++;
        }
    
    }
    else if(mouseX <= 300) {
        if(checkSpace(250) != -1) {
            fill(255, 0, 0);
            ellipse(250, (checkSpace(250)), 50, 50);
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
            turn++;
        }
```

No need for the extra conditions in the if as long as you use else if.